# create a Virtual server in virtualmin: mailbox failed, Bad File Descriptor

Tags: email, file-descriptors, webmin

I'm trying to create a Virtual server in virtualmin and everytime i click in create it displays an error :

> Creating mailbox for administration user ..
>   .. mailbox failed : Failed to write to /home/Domainname//var/mail/user when closing : Bad file descriptor at /usr/libexec/webmin/web-lib-funcs.pl line 1427.

I think I've tried everything possible , I've also rebooted my server .
I tried changing the account plan (i;e: disk quota) to unlimited .

But it shows the same error again and again .

What should i do now ??

Comment: does `/home/Domainname//var/mail/user` exist? I see a double slash there and perhaps webmin doesn't like it.

Comment: it does not !!!

Comment: @schaiba A double slash in a file name shouldn't be a problem. However, the name looks weird: `/home/Domainname/…` and `/var/mail/user` are plausible locations for a mailbox, but not this combination of the two. There must be a configuration error related to the mailbox path.

Comment: Gilles is correct. This is a mixup of two types of mail spool. It isn't a sensible configuration. Virtualmin and Webmin support either type of mailbox...but, that isn't how either would be configured.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to configure Virtualmin manually? The install script should have set that correctly for you; it should be $HOME/Maildir (assuming you don't have some reason to use the old mbox mailspool format). It doesn't make sense to use a traditional mail spool in var inside of the user's home.

If you're configuring it manually, you're in for a long day. This particular option needs to be configured in: Postfix, Procmail, Usermin, and Dovecot. Pretty much every service that touches mail needs to know where mail lives.

The next version of the installer allows individual services (web, mail, databases, etc.) to be enabled and configured independently at any time after installation. But, for now I don't have an easy script to point you to that will auto-configure your mail (there's an old mail setup script here: http://software.virtualmin.com/lib/mail-setup.pl but it's so old I don't recommend it for anything other than a reference for doing the steps manually). If this is a new system, and not in service yet, I'd recommend you start over and use the install script, and just let it setup mail for you.

If you did use the install script, and you've only changed this one option...just change it back (that's probably in the Postfix configuration, in main.cf, unless you're using another mail server) to the default ($HOME/Maildir).

If you used the install script and didn't change this option, there may be a bug, but I haven't seen anyone reporting it. What OS and version are you using?